# $mdToast Binding Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Materials $mdToast service but I'm having some issues accessing the parent controller.

I have a controller called `CalculationsListController`

Inside here I have my `$mdToast` instance

`$mdToast.show({
     templateUrl: 'app/features/settlement/calculations/toast.html',
     position: 'top right',
     hideDelay: 0,
     parent: $document[0].querySelector('#toast-container'),
     controllerAs: 'vm',
     bindToController: true
});`

In the template markup I have the following

`<md-toast class="error">
  <span translate translate-values="{unAllocatedJourneys: vm.unAllocatedJourneys.summary.total}">TOAST_MESSAGE.CALCULATION_REQUEST.UNALLOCATED_JOURNEYS</span>
    <md-button ng-click="vm.test()"><span translate>TOAST_MESSAGE.CALCULATION_REQUEST.FIND_OUT_MORE</span></md-button>
</md-toast>`

**Note** - My `vm.test()` & `vm.unAllocatedJourneys` are defined up top as properties in my controller

From the above, can anyone see why I may not have access to my vm properties on the parent controller?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the 'locals' field on the configuration object for binding the values to the toast controller

```
$mdToast.show({
    templateUrl: 'app/features/settlement/calculations/toast.html',
    position: 'top right',
    hideDelay: 0,
    parent: $document[0].querySelector('#toast-container'),
    controller: function() {},
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    locals: {
       unAllocatedJourneys: vm.unAllocatedJourneys
    }
});
```

or using the controller field to use the existing controller

```
$mdToast.show({
    templateUrl: 'app/features/settlement/calculations/toast.html',
    position: 'top right',
    hideDelay: 0,
    parent: $document[0].querySelector('#toast-container'),
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: vm
});
```

[Toast Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast)

Comment: Hello Graham, I have actually read the same thing but using locals still wont work as it is doing the same thing as what bindToController is doing. They mention that using bindToController binds our local variables without having to pass them in - `bindToController - bool: bind the locals to the controller, instead of passing them in`

Comment: I've added an empty controller declaration - try that. I was able to pass in a variable and read it by using vm.variableName in my toast template

Comment: Thank you Graham - You've put me on the right path a lot of fiddling about with this one! Top guy, thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, feel free to accept the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: I can't accept it as the solution because it didn't solve my issue but I will upvote it as it did get me on the right path. If I mark it as an accepted answer it may be misleading to another :)

Comment: The empty controller declaration solved the issues I was having. It would be great if in the past 5 years they could have actually documented how to use this tool.

Answer (score 0):

you should open your modal with current scope:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   scope: $scope
});
```

where $scope, is scope of CalculationsListController